# Connect to a VPN from a .NET app on Windows Azure?

Tags: .net, azure, vpn

Does anyone know how to connect to an existing VPN from a .NET app running from a worker role in Windows Azure?

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same thing. Has anything changed in the past 3 years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure connect. You need to install the client software on the machine with the network you wish to access.